# How to set name to the JObject by c#?

Tags: c#, json

I get the json from server, add JObject to the JArray.
I want to set a name to that json. I do not know how to do it.

```
foreach(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  var array = new JArray();
  var jsonFromServer = GetDataFromServer();
  var strAsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonFromServer);
  array.Add(strAsJson);
}
```

I am having now:

```
[
{...},
{...},
{...}
]
```

My task is:

```
[
"0": {...},
"1": {...},
"2": {...}
]
```

I can not to set the name to the JObject. I can to add the name to the JProperty, but I can not to add JProperty to JArray, because it is not a JObject. I can use the JObject instead and add the json to JsonProperty, but I have to use the JArray.

Comment: The desired JSON you show in your question is invalid.  You cannot put properties (key-value pairs) directly inside an array in JSON.  They must be inside objects.  See [json.org](http://json.org/). You could do `[ { "0": { ... }}, { "1": {...}}, { "2": {...}} ]` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
var obj = new JObject();
obj.Add($"{i}", strAsJson);

array.Add(obj);
```

Or this handy one-liner:

```
array.Add(new JObject(new JProperty($"{i}", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFromServer))));
```

Comment: Thank you. I just have known, that it is impossible to set the name of JObject in JArray, how it is above.